# Check if word is inside of list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering how I can efficiently check whether a value is inside a given list of tuples. Say I have a list of:

```
("the", 1)
("check", 1)
("brown, 2)
("gary", 5)
```

how can I check whether a given word is inside the list, ignoring the second value of the tuples? If it was just a word I could use

```
if "the" in wordlist:
   #...
```

but this will not work, is there something along the line this i can do?

```
if ("the", _) in wordlist:
   #...
```

Comment: what is more efficient will depend if you have to do it just once, or many times with the same worldlist

Answer (score 14, accepted):

May be use a hash

```
>>> word in dict(list_of_tuples)
```

Comment: Very pragmatic solution. Perfect.

Comment: this is a great suggestion and even easier than my zip :P

Comment: and If I needed to access that position after as well, is there an easy solution similar to this?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose this uses python __contains__ on the dictionary which only tell you whether the membership exists or not.  Also this dictionary is orderless.  If you need the index then either go for JoranBeasley solution replacing the second line as words.index('word').  or Use an OrderedDict(list_of_tuples).keys().index(word).

Comment: if the list is very long, a short-circuiting solution might be better

Answer (score 6):

Use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(word[0] == 'the' for word in wordlist):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

Lookup of the word in the list will be O(n) time complexity, so the more words in the list, the slower find will work. To speed up you may sort a list by word as a key alphabeticaly and then use binary search - search of the word becomes log(N) complexity, but the most efficient way is to use hashing with the set structure:

```
'the' in set((word for word, _ in a))
```

O(1), independent of how many words are in the set. BTW, it guarantees that only one instance of the word is inside the structure, while list can hold as many "the" as many you append. Set should be constructed once, add words with the .add method(add new word is O(1) complexity too)

Comment: but the sorting is N*log(N)

Comment: @wim, definitely! The topicstarter asked about lookup, I had answered the lookup timings. Generaly talking in the context of efficiency is impossible without more knowledge about the data use, e.g. how often the words added to the list against lookups.

Answer (score 1):

```
for tupl in wordlist:
    if 'the' in tupl:
        # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words,scores = zip(*wordlist)
```

to split the wordlist into a list of words and a list of scores then just

```
print "the" in words
```

Comment: Brief replies are perfectly acceptable but splitting off your narrative from the code block and supplying a sentence or two by way of explanation goes a long way to creating a quality reply.